# Store file in PostgreSQL database using NodeJS and Angular2+

Tags: node.js, angular, postgresql, express, pg-promise

I have read a lot of examples/tutorials on internet that explain how to upload and store files in PostgreSQL using NodeJS, Multer, Sequelize, Express, ...

With none of them I have understood how to do it in my project.

I have an Angular app where I have an input file, I have an API in NodeJS using pg-promise to link with my PostgreSQL database. I have done all my project api with pg-promise so I would like to use it and no Sequelize.

In the database I have read that the best is probably the BYTEA type for files like jpg, png, pdf, docx...

Here is my API hierarchy :

[image]

`www` file contains code to initiate the server

`app.js` file contains code to initiate express app and the `require([library])` of what I need

`index.js` file contains code to link urls to function that are stored in `queries.js`

The only thing I want is **How to store a file**.

Thanks if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you the use of `multer` library. It helps you with the storage of files in disk. You get the path where it is stored, and you could save the path on the database.

https://github.com/expressjs/multer